# Invoke method with parameters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, отладка, рефлексия

У меня есть проблема с рефлексией.

Сама суть: есть куча методов в классе. Я нахожу нужный таким образом (здесь все хорошо):

```
invokingMethod = InstanceClass.getMethod(AMethodName, AArgumentTypes);
```

далее я его хочу вызвать:

```
result = invokingMethod.invoke(AInstance, AArgumentObjects);
```

Содержимое AArgumentObjects:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в итоге у меня выбрасывается ошибка про неверное тип переданных параметров.

Работает только, если явно передавать все параметры в функцию. Или использую AArgumentObjects[1] в переменной debug меню (если поменять в коде, то ошибки так и остаются):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После вызова из кода с AArgumentObjects[1]:

Выбрасывается : `"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"`

Больше информации в аналогичном вопросе только на английском языке:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278807/invoke-method-with-parameters?noredirect=1#comment77520254_45278807

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему таким образом:

```
result = invokingMethod.invoke(AInstance, ((Object[])AArgumentObjects[1]));
```